# Rewrite code containing Microsoft.Action delegate using the System.Action delegate

Tags: c#, .net

The old project has code like

```
Microsoft.Action<StringBuilder, string, string, string, bool> appendTag = 
    (StringBuilder sb, string tagName, string curVal, string priorVal, 
        bool checkPrior) =>
        {
            if (generateEmptyTags || curVal != string.Empty)
            {
                sb.Append("<");
                sb.Append(tagName);

                if (checkPrior && (generateEmptyTags || foundPrior))
                {
                    sb.Append(" prior_value=\"");
                    sb.Append(priorVal.XmlEncoded());
                    sb.Append("\"");
                }
                sb.Append(">");
                sb.Append(curVal.XmlEncoded());
                sb.Append("</");
                sb.Append(tagName);
                sb.Append(">");
            }
        };
```

At present the reference of Microsoft object is removed, so can someone help with rewriting inline function using Lambda and Linq, without `Microsoft.Action` delegate. The new inline function should accept four parameters.
No idea of Lambda and Linq so need help with this.

The project is in .Net framework 3.5 and hence System.Action accepts only 4 parameters and errors out:

I had also tried System.Action but it gives Compilation error 
       System.Action' requires '4' type argument.

So now need help to write my own inline function which would replace the Microsoft.Action

Comment: Does this not compile when you remove `Microsoft.` part from the declaration? What error do you get?

Comment: You should be able to simply replace Microsoft.Action with System.Action and recompile.

Comment: @ErikFunkenbusch : put that into an answer, because it's exactly  this question

Comment: @resthere if you take a look into the [docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397687.aspx) when you will easily see what your code is already using lambda functions.

Comment: @ErikFunkenbusch the System.Action does not accept 5 parameters.Error is Using the generic type 'System.Action<T1,T2,T3,T4>' requires '4' type arguments

Comment: @resthere - System.Action can take up to 16 parameters.. not sure why you think it can't...  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/018hxwa8(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: @Fedor I agree that the code uses Lambda but my question is , since current code is using Microsoft.Action delegate how do I write my own lambda function to replace this(Microsoft.Action)

Comment: @ErikFunkenbusc look at the error System.Action<T1,T2,T3,T4>' requires '4' type argument  This error I get when I compile. I am using .net framework 3.5

Comment: @resthere - Oh, you didn't mention you were using a version of .NET from last decade... That's why they were using Microsoft.Action most likely, because the 3.5 version only supported 4 arguments max.  Microsoft.Action was released by Microsoft to allowed .NET 3.5 applications to use the same functionality as .NET 4 and later.. why would you want to replace it then?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, hello .NET 3.5!

You could define your own delegate to bypass the .NET 3.5 limitations:

```
public delegate void Action<T1,T2,T3,T4,T5>
  (StringBuilder arg1, string arg2, string arg3, string arg4, bool arg5);
```

Given that, the following code will compile:

```
Action<StringBuilder, string, string, string, bool> appendTag =
  (StringBuilder sb, string tagName, string curVal, string priorVal, bool checkPrior) =>
    {
      ...
    };
```

This solution may be less intrusive than pkuderov's answer, which is the other good alternative. That's up to you to determine which one is better for your own situation.

Answer (score 1):

Since that comment `look at the error System.Action<T1,T2,T3,T4>' requires '4' type argument This error I get when I compile. I am using .net framework 3.5` I advice you to reduce the number of arguments to 2.
Create struct which will accommodate `string tagName, string curVal, string priorVal, bool checkPrior` and pass its object to `Action<StringBuilder, YourStruct>` and refactor the body of your lambda to satisfy this transformation.

Comment: In the current project the Microsoft.Action delegate  is used all over, so at every place I would have to refactor lambda at each and every place. So the solution of Patrice would be easy to implement.